# assign list elements to database entity in sqlalchemy from a list

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a simple model as follows, i have a list of games and i want all the players to assign one and only one game, from the list of games. How would i do it in sqlalchemy. 
As of now i am using flask sqlalchemy, but the question does not limit to flask-sqlalchemy.

```
games = ['soccer', 'hockey', 'baseball', 'cricket', 'basketball']

from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

class Gamer(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    team_name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    game_name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    game = db.Column(db.String(80), i want only games from the list of games)
```

The analogous django functionality is found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#setting-arguments-for-widgets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the django functionality you refer to is not really *analogous* to the model you list. The reason for this is that `Gamer` is a `model` whereas `SimpleForm` is a UI `form`.

However, below are few ways you can validate the `model`:

1) Create a separate tabbe for `Games`, add the values as rows, and create a `N-to-1` relationship from `Gamer` to the `Game`. This is readable, and will validate your data on both the business and DB levels

```
class Game(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))

class Gamer(db.Model):
    # ...
    game_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('game.id'))
    game = relationship(Game)
```

2) Create and use a [simple validator](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/mapper_config.html#simple-validators)

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import validates
class Gamer(db.Model):
    # ...
    @validates('game')
    def validate_game(self, key, address):
        assert address in games
        return address
```

---

**edit-1:** alternatively, take a look at the [The Enum Recipe](http://techspot.zzzeek.org/2011/01/14/the-enum-recipe/). But again this is on a model level, not UI validation.